# Read existing PDF file with all format information

Tags: pdf

I want to read an existing PDF file, get not only the text, but also the format information like: Font (Bold, Italic...), and paragraphs... Is there an code library for doing this, is it open source or commercial?

I am on Windows and favor C# libraries, but C/C++ is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can very much recommend 
pdflib (http://www.pdflib.com/). 
Its commercial, but it also has a lite version which you can use for free privately. It contains very muach functionality and is available for all plattforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'd echo Mr. Meyers on this. There appear to be a number of them; search for "pdf parser library" (plus your language) in your favorite search engine.

A few top hits:

http://www.lowagie.com/iText/

http://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Parse

http://podofo.sourceforge.net/

http://www.vicman.net/download/13733/ (several for .NET)

Note that if you're wanting to edit an existing PDF, you might want to read this:

http://1t3xt.info/tutorials/faq.php?branch=faq.pdf_in_general&node=replace_word

Comment: Thanks TrueWill, I've searched before and found some of them may have powerful ability in creating PDF while not as powerful when parsing, I hope get some guidence from someone experienced so I could jump to the right direction without spending too much time to evalute all those libraries.

Comment: And after reading the article you recommended, I am pessimistic about if there is such a library

Answer (score 0):

The Pdfium.Net SDK  also can help you. Via this API you can get access to a  collection of text, images and other objects and ther properties. 
Please note I work at the company who develop this API.